# is there a way to open text file in notepad++ from python script in other some other IDE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, notepad++

I am trying to open a text file from python script written in pycharm in notepad++ I found from  the previous answers that we can use the command in the python from the subprocess module to open the specific file but I want to open the notepad++ to open a file at specific line 
I used  this

```
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call([r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", r"C:\location\myfile.txt"])
```

but it is opening without any specific focus but i know the following command prompt option to open the my text file at specific line using below command line command

```
start notepad++ "C:\location\myfile.txt" -n1500
```

this is opening the myfile.txt at line number 1500 highlighted in notepad++ but when I am trying to add the `-n(line-number)` to the `subprocess.call([r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", r"C"\location\myfile.txt"])` the it is  not able to execute. Is there any way to execute this command in python script using subprocess or os module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you actually can, by appending the additional arguments to the list of arguments that was already specified.  The following should achieve the command launched from the command line:

```
subprocess.call([
    r"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe", r"C:\location\myfile.txt",
    "-n1500"
])
```